# Stopping blocking sockets in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, network-programming, timeout

I have a java socket calling a server. However, I do not know at which address I can reach the server, so I put several sockets in several threads and they try to reach the server each on one address. My probem is that I do not want to wait for the timeout but have no idea how to stop the sockets and their threads properly.

Code:

```
socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(endpoint, timeout); // **Blocking method**
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
//Write Data here
```

How can I interrupt the operation? I consider `Thread.stop()` a bad style and it also does not work properly. *.NET* Tcp Endpoints have a non-blocking `pending` method that allows uinsg boolean flags but I could not find something similiar

Comment: Try either interrupting the thread with `thread.interrupt()` or closing the socket. Both should throw an exception.

Comment: Can you add a timeout to the socket? After timing out, let the thread stop. Calling `Thread.interrupt` is not recommended.

Comment: I don't want a too long timeout since the application should not run too long @prasanth

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know at which address I can reach the server, so I put
>   several sockets in several threads and they try to reach the server
>   each on one address.

BAD. BAD Decision. Perform some logical step to determine the server's address. Or, perform something that helps you know about the server's IP-Address.

Do this way, only if it is the last hope.

> My problem is that I do not want to wait for the
>   timeout but have no idea how to stop the sockets and their threads
>   properly.

You don't have any other option that timeout. Socket.connect() is blocking. You can't do anything than waiting.

You've to wait for timeout because that is the logical way to close the socket object created. You can't just do close directly, until a timeout. Reduce the timeout to the limit when your result should come(connection should be accepted).

> How can I interrupt the operation? I consider Thread.stop() a bad
>   style and it also does not work properly.

Yes, you should not perform Thread.stop() or Thread.interrupt(). These are bad programming styles.

If the timeout expires, make the close() operation on socket.

You should set a socket timeout for the client-socket. It is the best-practice to set a timeout for sockets. The timeout should be around 10 seconds to more depending on the needs.

You can set the timeout in your current code by calling

1. [`socket.setSoTimeout(timeout);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout(int)) for reading timeout, OR
2. for connect timeout, [`connect(endpoint,timeout)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress,%20int)) as you've done in your code.

If the timeout expires, a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` is raised, though the Socket is still valid. The timeout must be > 0. A timeout of zero is interpreted as an infinite timeout.

You're probably not using a try-catch-finally in your code. That'd be a better design here.

As you're doing a connect timeout, so your code can be amended to exit the blocking method like as shown below :

```
try{
   socket = new Socket();
   socket.connect(endpoint,timeout); // **Blocking method**
   OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
   //Write Data here
}
catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
   socket.close();
}
```

Comment: `Socket.setSoTimeout()` sets a read timeout. `connect(endpoint, timeout)` causes a connect timeout. They are not the same thing, or equivalent.

Comment: The situation is that there's only a set of adresses and there is no such logical step to find them

Comment: @chr - If such is the case, then it is OK. Then that means you only have limited options of servers to connect to. Then you can go with this approach.

Comment: @chr - If my answer helped, you may like to upvote them. Also, if it does, please accept them! Thanks.